Creating API to Login User in Django
The main error here is basically django doesn't recognizing authentication outside admin page and my main login  view
I'm trying to apply authentication in my api, as a way to study apis building
in django, I have this view in my api app:
@api_view(['POST'])
def loginUser(request):
data = request.data
serializer = UserLoginSerializer(data=data)

if serializer.is_valid():
    
    serializer.perform_login()
    return Response({"Success:", "User logged succesfully"},status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
else:
    print(serializer.is_valid())
    return Response({"ERROR":"NO PERMISSION."}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

For this view, I have this REST formalizer:
class UserLoginSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
username = serializers.CharField()
password = serializers.CharField()

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username','password']

def validate(self,validated_data):
    user = authenticate(username=validated_data['username'],password=validated_data['password'])
    if not user:
        raise ValidationError("user doesn't exist.")
    validated_data['user'] = user
    return validated_data
def perform_login(self):
    user = self.validated_data['user']
    print(user)
    login(user)

Consider all the prints in the view and in the formalizer a humble way to understand what's happening with
The problem is: No Wrong information, no invalid credential, testing and testing through shell, through postman, through everything. username=x password=y, whatever is the data, being valid credentials or not, error is being returned
CHATGPT warned me it could be because of importing the AbstractUser function for the User model and not AbstractBaseModel, BUT it's working fine for user authentication in my main view and in django admin

Is your frontend separate from Django? How are you logging in there? How are you requesting these APIs?
